# How do you enforce a blank space in a validation rule?

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule

I'm trying to enforce the blank space in the Canadian zip code validation but can't get it to work.  Zip code needs to be A9A 9A9,  it cannot be A9A9A9.

Here's my syntax:

```
and(
    (NOT(REGEX(Zip_vod__c, "^((?i)[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\\d[A-Z]?\\s?\\d[A-Z]\\d)?"))), 
    (UPPER($User.Country) = "CA"), 
    NOT(CONTAINS( $Profile.Name , "INTEGRATION")) 
)
```

I've also tried:

```
and(
    (NOT(REGEX(Zip_vod__c, "^((?i)[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\\d[A-Z]?\\ \\d[A-Z]\\d)?"))), 
    (UPPER($User.Country) = "CA"), 
    NOT(CONTAINS( $Profile.Name , "INTEGRATION")) 
)
```

and:

```
and(
    (NOT(REGEX(Zip_vod__c, "^((?i)[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\\d[A-Z]?\\[blank space]\\d[A-Z]\\d)?"))), 
    (UPPER($User.Country) = "CA"), 
    NOT(CONTAINS( $Profile.Name , "INTEGRATION")) 
)
```

and:

```
and(
    (NOT(REGEX(Zip_vod__c, "^((?i)[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\\d[A-Z]?\\[]\\d[A-Z]\\d)?"))), 
    (UPPER($User.Country) = "CA"), 
    NOT(CONTAINS( $Profile.Name , "INTEGRATION")) 
)
```

Comment: Why do you care how it's formatted?

Comment: You could compare `zip_vod__c != deleteWhitespace(zip_vod__c)` ; this wouldn't enforce proper format but at least ensure a space exists

Comment: @adrianlarson its a requirement based off of customer master integration.

Comment: @jatuttle0 I'd need to enforce the format as well, but thanks!

Comment: Can you please verify observed behavior and how it compares to your expectation? What values did you try? Did they validate? Should they have?

Comment: I was able to figure it out.                                                           NOT(REGEX(Zip_vod__c, "^((?i)[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\\d[A-Z]?.*\\s.*\\d[A-Z]\\d)?"))),                                This does not allow A9A9A9 and enforces the space so that it must follow A9A 9A9.